# Create a single mesh by combining the points where two meshes meet using Geometry Node or python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, procedural, intersection

I am studying Geometry Node in Blender and I am currently facing the problem of creating a mesh between two curves using Procedural.

Several curves were set using Curve, and meshes were placed at regular intervals along the curves. But the question is where the curves meet. At the point where they meet, they overlap like the boxes in the first photo.

[image]

[image]

The problem I want to solve is that I want to create a single mesh by stretching the box to the length between the two curves, like the white box in the second picture, without overlapping. (only length, not thickness)

[image]

The nodes currently in progress are as follows

Please tell me the solution, Blender experts.

[image]